# Best practices for displaying different data when using the same partials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scopes

Just a question related to Rails best practices:

Say we have a Post and a Comment model. The same partial is used to render the post on both the index view and the show view. Inside that partial is a reference to another partial that renders the comments.

**post_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

**_post.html.haml**

```
.post
  = post.content 
  = render 'comments/list', :comments => post.comments
```

**comments/_list.html.haml**

```
- comments.each do |c|
    c.comment
```

Let's now say that for the post index view, we only want to display the last 3 comments for each post, yet on the show view we want to display all comments for the post. Because the same partial is used, we can't edit the call to limit the comments. What's the best way to achieve this? Currently I've abstracted this out to a helper, however it feels a little dodgy:

```
def limited_comments(comments)
  if params[:controller] == 'posts' and params[:action] == 'show'
    comments
  else
    comments.limit(3)
  end
end
```

Which means **_post.html.haml** is changed to read

```
= render 'comments/list', :comments => limited_comments(post.comments)
```

It works, but doesn't feel like the Rails way. I'm guessing there's a way with scopes, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what @benchwarmer wanted to say is that it's better to pass a parameter to _post partial. Straightforward @comments doesn't work, but something like the code below might:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  render :partial => @posts, :locals => { :max_comments => 3 }
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  render :partial => @post, :locals => { :max_comments => false }
end
```

In post.html.haml:

```
= render 'comments/list', :comments => limited_comments(post.comments,max_comments)
```

Your helper:

```
def limited_comments(comments,max_comments)
  max_comments ? comments.limit(max_comments) : comments
end
```

I didn't compile, so you may need to further work on parameters that you pass to render :partial (may be you'll have to separately set :partial and :object/:collection in this case, or smth else, I don't remember and didn't try). But I hope, the idea is clear - keep the logical representation (all comments or last 3) separate from processing path (which controller/action). May be you'll later want to display posts with comments embedded in yet another list (last 3 posts for a list of users), then such separation will come handy.

If you don't want to expose all your internal logical details at controller level, you can also do smth like:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  render :partial => @posts, :locals => { :comments_list_type => :short }
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  render :partial => @post, :locals => { :comments_list_type => :full }
end
```

Then, in post.html.haml:

```
= render 'comments/list', :comments => build_comments_list(post.comments,comments_list_type)
```

Your helper:

```
def limited_comments(comments,comments_list_type)
  case comments_list_type
    when :short
      comments.limit(3) 
    when :long
      comments.limit(10) 
    when :full
      comments
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, setting that `max_comments` variable makes much more sense. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This is good, but you can go slightly further and change the helper to make max_comments an optional argument, default to nil. `comments.limit(nil)` will not apply a limit to the query. So that gets rid of a conditional, and where you would have passed max_comments as `false` you can just omit the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can last 3 comments on the index action and assign into `@comments` variable and for show action you can load all the comments for that post. So it becomes

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  @comments = Comment.order("created_at desc").limit(3)
end

def show
  @posts = Post.all
  @comments = @post.comments.order("created_at desc").limit(3)
end
```

In the view its simply

```
= render 'comments/list', :comments => @comments
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this just lists *all* comments in the index view. My comments are tied to posts, and I want to retrieve the last 3 for *each individual post*. Hopefully this makes sense, and I've updated the question to explain this.